# How to write out the gradient of $f$ evaluated at $a$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose $a, b, c$ are all vectors of length $n$. Let $f(b, c) = ||b - c||^2_2$. I want to write down the gradient of $f$ wrt to $c$ evaluated at $a$. Is the following the correct notation?

$\nabla f(a) = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial c_1}(a_1), \ldots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial c_n}(a_n) \right) = -2(b - a)$

Is there a more concise way of writing it, or is the above the standard way to do it?

Comment: $\nabla f(x)$ is pretty standard notation. But, it must be noted that this means
$$(\nabla f)(x)$$
And not
$$\nabla(f(x))$$

Comment: @K.defaoite Thanks. Do I need to specify what I'm taking the gradient with respect to? That is, if I were to write $(\nabla f)(a)$, it's unclear to me what I'm taking the partial derivative with respect to (which in this case is $c$)?

Comment: Do you consider $b$ to be held constant?

Comment: Yes, $b$ is constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we consider $\underline{\mathrm{b}}$ to be a constant vector, then we can write our function $f$ as
$$f(\underline{\mathrm{x}};\underline{\mathrm{b}})=\sum_{i=1}^n(b_i-x_i)^2$$
Observe ($\partial_k$ is shorthand for $\partial/\partial x_k$)
$$\partial_k f(\underline{\mathrm{x}};\underline{\mathrm{b}})=2x_k-2b_k$$
So
$$\nabla f(\underline{\mathrm{x}};\underline{\mathrm{b}})=2\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-b_i)\underline{\mathrm{e}_i}$$
$$\nabla f(\underline{\mathrm{x}};\underline{\mathrm{b}})=2(\underline{\mathrm{x}}-\underline{\mathrm{b}})$$
We can just replace
$$\nabla f(\underline{\mathrm{a}};\underline{\mathrm{b}})=2(\underline{\mathrm{a}}-\underline{\mathrm{b}})$$
Is anything unclear?